# Printing a Multi-page Listview

Tags: c#, listview

Ok, I have got a `printDocument1_PrintPage` method which is supposed to print out the contents of a `ListView`. During execution, the method only prints out the first page. Could someone help me to printout the remaining page(s)?

I have identified the end of the first page via the variable `ypos` and set the property `e.HasMorePages = true`.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
  Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
  int ypos = 78;
  Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightSlateGray);
  graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(10, 10, 770, 50));
  Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black);
  Pen graypen = new Pen(Color.LightGray);
  Pen redpen = new Pen(Color.Red);
  graphics.DrawRectangle(blackpen, new Rectangle(10, 10, 770, 50));
  Brush B = new SolidBrush(listView1.ForeColor);

  graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 10, 10, 10, 1132);
  graphics.DrawString("FORENAME", f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 25));
  graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 130, 10, 130, 1132);
  graphics.DrawString("SURNAME", f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(140, 25));
  graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 290, 10, 290, 1132);
  graphics.DrawString("EXT.", f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(300, 25));
  graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 380, 10, 380, 1132);
  graphics.DrawString("JOB TITLE", f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(410, 25));
  graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, 780, 10, 780, 1132);

  int[] X = { 15, 140, 300, 390, 720 }; 
  int Y = 60; 
  f1 = listView1.Font;

  for (int I = 0; I < listView1.Items.Count; I++){
     for (int J = 0; J < listView1.Items[I].SubItems.Count - 1; J++){
        graphics.DrawString(listView1.Items[I].SubItems[J].Text, f1, B, X[J], Y);
     }
     Y += f1.Height;
     graphics.DrawLine(graypen, 10, ypos, 780, ypos);
     ypos = ypos + 17;

     if (ypos > 1132){
       e.HasMorePages = true;
       return;                   
     }
   }
   graphics.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: PrintPage gets called multiple times for multiple pages, so your "I" variable (should be lower case by the way) needs to be scoped outside that method.  A for-loop is hard to make it work right in that scenario, so use a do-loop instead.  Dispose your drawing tools.

Comment: For one thing, do not dispose of that Graphics object you did not create it so it is not your job to dispose of it (also no need to copy to a new var),  The row and Y tracker vars need to be declared outside the method since you want P2 to pick up where you left off.

Comment: Thanks to LarsTech and  Plutonix for the suggestions.. I'll try them and post the results... Thanks again!